# Creating a Haarcascade Classifier

Tags: c#, emgucv, haar-classifier

I'm looking for a simple way to create a car classifier for haarcascade (I understand there are some classifiers already allover the internet) I need to train it on front view since I'm working on a vehicle accident prevention that detect cars coming from behind

I've been searching for weeks for a great tutorial but they just don't work or there is something wrong(broken links)

I'm using Windows and c# (EmguCV) and I'm using the latest dll files (since lots of functions are deprecated)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It worked for me. http://www.tectute.com/2011/06/opencv-haartraining.html
This video kind of explains the same procedure but it's much more clear.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFC6jxBKtBQ

P.S I'm not the author of any of these resources.